# Using dialogflow library in App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, library

I am trying to integrate Dialoogflow V2 into my Python/Django WebApp in GAE Flexible Environment.
I have followed all the steps:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/dialogflow/v2beta1

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring

The integration works fine locally.
Once deployed on the Cloud (no errors on deployment), the application doesnt seem to find the dialogflow library, and throws the error:
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'dialogflow'

Is there anything missing ?
How can I get the dialogflow library into GAE Flex ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Looks you've resolved this per SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436621/using-dialogflow-library-in-app-engine-flexible-environment; do you have further issue here?

Comment: Yes, resolved. posted the answer here as well for closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

The problem was that the appengine_config.py file was not understood by the GAE. The documentation here (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring) is insufficient.

I included this (https://gist.github.com/jonparrott/4bdd7af14a676f33b099) in my appengine_config.py, excluding the imports of os.path and sys, and that did the trick !